# While reading the data from output excel,it shows error in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium

```
FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\test_grid.xls");  
Workbook CPT_check =Workbook.getWorkbook(f2);
Sheet c1=CPT_check.getSheet(0);
String CPT_check_final =c1.getCell(2,7).getContents();

if(Final_result==CPT_check_final)
    System.out.println("CPT " +Final_result+" is correct");
else
    System.out.println("CPT " +Final_result+" is not correct");
```

This is my code and when I run it, it shows error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:318)
    at login.Login_first.main(Login_first.java:135)
```

The scenario is I write the data in excel using my code and from the same excel i need to read the data. So i tried my above code. it shows error. PLease help me out of this.

Comment: It seems, that cell 2,7 does not exist. Try to open your xls file manually and check the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to get the content of the cell

```
   FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream("D:\\Screenshot\\test_grid.xls");  
   Workbook CPT_check =Workbook.getWorkbook(f2);
   Sheet c1=CPT_check.getSheet(0);

   for(int rows=0;rows<c1.getRows();rows++)
   { 
   for(int cols=0;cols<c1.getColumns();cols++)
   { 
   System.out.println(c1.getCell(cols, rows).getContents().trim()); 
   }
   }
```